# getContentResolver().insert() всегда возвращает null

Tags: android, аудио, android-notification

Привет всем) Уже больше суток сижу с проблемой, хочу по клику на кнопку сделать так, чтобы ставился случайный рингтон из папки с рингтонами. Нашел кучу одинаковых гайдов, но в чем проблема так и не понял.

Вот код функции которая возвращает Uri рингтона записанного в базу:

```
private Uri getRandomUri() {
    File[] ringtones_array = getExternalFilesDir("Testringtones").listFiles();
    Random rnd = new Random();

    File ringtone_file = ringtones_array[rnd.nextInt(ringtones_array.length)];

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, ringtone_file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "myringtone");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "None");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, ringtone_file.getTotalSpace());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(ringtone_file.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + ringtone_file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);//всегда null

    return newUri;
}
```

В манифесте добавил:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

и далее получил разрешение.
В логах ошибок нет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что путь до файла не должен содержать точек, иначе он не пишется в базу и getContentResolver().insert(uri, values) возвращает null

Comment: А про какие точки вы говорите?